# Connect local USB printer to work on azure website

Tags: azure, webforms, azure-web-app-service

I am a student and working on a project on my practice. 
I have a database on Azure and my website that is connected to the database is also on Azure.
But now I want to print a POS-label from the website. The label I want to print is in code from Visual studio.

But when I try to print from the website it says: Settings to access printer are not valid.
How can I fix that? I have read that some people making a virtual machine on Azure and work from there.

I can't use `javascript:Window.Print()` because I don't want to print anything from the website, just from code.

```
var ps = new PrinterSettings();
            ps.PrinterName = "Brother QL-500";
            var size = new PaperSize("My Size", 2, 1);
            ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = size;
            recordDoc.PrinterSettings = ps;
            recordDoc.Print();
```

Comment: Give more information.

Comment: i have this code in visual studio: PrintDocument recordDoc = new PrintDocument();
                recordDoc.DocumentName = "Tire Receipt";
                recordDoc.PrintPage += PrintReceiptPage;
                recordDoc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();               
                var ps = new PrinterSettings();
                ps.PrinterName = "Brother QL-500";
                var size = new PaperSize("My Size", 2, 1);
                ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = size;
                recordDoc.PrinterSettings = ps;
                recordDoc.Print();

Comment: and in printreceiptPage function i have: // Draw string to screen.
            string text = "275/55 R 22";
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, drawFontArial26Bold, drawBrush, new RectangleF(x, y, width, height), drawFormatCenter);
            //y += e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, drawFontArial26Bold).Height;

Comment: @AndreasPettersson First: Please do *not* shove a bunch of code into comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question and properly format your code there. Second: Where, exactly, do you expect this label to print?

Comment: Sorry im totally new.
when I press a button on my website. Values from dropdownlist is going to print on a label.
on recordDoc.Print(); I will to print.